# Convergence of $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^\alpha} ds$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I need to see if the following integral converges:

$I= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^\alpha} ds \ ,  \ 0<\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

What I did is divide it in two parts:

$ I =  \int_1^{2} \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^\alpha} ds  + \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^\alpha} ds$

the first one converges because the integrand is continuous and the interval is bounded. The second one converges because $ (s-1)^\alpha  > 1$ for $s >2 $ so :

$  \int_2^{\infty} \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^\alpha} ds < \int_2^{\infty} e^{-s}ds = e^{-2}$

From this I get that the integral must converge for all $\alpha$ considered.

The problem I have is that when I introduce it in [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1+to+oo+%28e%5E%28-s%29%2F%28s-1%29%5Ea%29) it adds a restraint in $\alpha$ i.e. $\alpha < 1$

Could you tell were I went wrong or why Wolfram gives that answer?

Comment: Note that the function has a pole at $s=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{e^{-s}}{(s-1)^{\alpha}} $$
is not bounded (and hence not continuous) on $[1,2]$: the denominator tends to zero. However, it is bounded by $e^{-1}(s-1)^{\alpha}$ there, since $e^{-s} \leqslant e^{-1}$ on $[1,2]$. But then
$$ \int_{1+\varepsilon}^2 \frac{ds}{(s-1)^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{1-\alpha}(1-\varepsilon^{1-\alpha}), $$
which only converges to a limit as $\varepsilon \downarrow 0$ if $\alpha<1$. The case $\alpha=1$ has to be checked separately (it still diverges, but logarithmically).